# Can't connect to SQL Server by name

Tags: sql-server

I'm wondering how can I possibly troubleshoot this. One of our client is having trouble connecting to our server, I went in and used HeidiSQL to see if it can simply establish a connection. It seems that it can connect to the IP address but not the address. All of our clients connect fine except this one client.

What could be the issue? Could it be the host files?

Connection is made through connection string

Comment: Could be hosts file, could be  DNS issues. could be lots of things.  Open up a command prompt and type `nslookup name.of.sql.server` and see what you get back. That would be my first step in troubleshooting

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to resolve that name to IP? Might be a DNS issue. In the end an easy fix will be to edit the hostfile to resolve the name to your IP, but this requires maintenance on the machine if that IP ever changes.

A better fix will be to figure out why the name isn't resolving to the correct IP address.